# How to use existing db2 sequence using jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, db2

I want to use existing db2 sequence, I tried with

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_GENERATOR")
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "MY_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
 private Integer id
```

But by using this, Data saving properly but strange is that in db id is storing. e.g 3 and returning 2 to me. and for each run it is id generating like,

```
In dB | to me

  3   |  2

  5   |  4

  7   |  6

  9   |  8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem, by dropping sequence trigger, which was executing before each insert because of that it is generating wrong ids.

Hibernate and DB sequences was running.

Answer (score 0):

Call to get the last identity entered.

```
SELECT IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() INTO :RESULT FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

If the sequence is off like after a restore alter table to reset it.